# Some trash in CMD while using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1VjA.png)I made a parser which is working OK in Pycharm, have no troubles and debagger also shows nothing. But when I make an .exe file (I am using pyinstaller to do that) I have some trash in CMD. Script is working OK but this trash is looking awful. Maybe someone can tell me where is the problem

I used this earlier,

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

but now my imports are looking like that:

```
import csv
import time
from time import sleep as pause

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **trash in CMD**?